# Is there a way to print a dataframe with a grid in IDLE?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While working in Jupyter Notebook, when I display my dataframe without using print(), it shows a grid. Like this:
[image: Sample dataframe output without using print]

Is there a way to display a dataframe in python IDLE the same way with/without the grid?

I just want all the value of one column to be printed in same indent, like in the image attached.

P.S I'm getting the values of dataframe from a MySQL table using mysql.connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use user defined functions to print the data frames in a grid pattern.
Or I recommend you to use the library [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/).
A sample code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'First Column' : [1, 2, 3, 4],'Second Column' : ['cell 1', 'cell 2', 'cell 3', 'cell 4']})
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple'))
```

you can change the values of the attribute tablefmt. Just check the documentation page of the tabular library.
Change `tablefmt= 'grid'` to change the display format.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm getting the data from an underlying MySql database table so it will be difficult to do this...Any other methods?

Comment: @Freesoul , It wont be difficult . It dosen't matters where ever you are getting the data. It only matters if the current data is a data frame or not. If df is the dataframe, you can use the line "print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='grid')) " to print the dataframe in grid form

Answer (score 0):

You may use `df.head()`, but know that IDLE automatically squeezes text larger than 50 lines, by default.

[image]

You may change this behavior, or your `df.head()` with less than 50 lines.